# upgrade from 2.0.5 to 2.2.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

I have old app. It based on CakePHP 2.0.5.
I want to upgrade it to current latest version, 2.2.5.

Is it enough to replace new `lib` folder with the old one? or application folder needs to be changed, too.

(checking changelogs for about 17 versions takes time a lot!!!)

Comment: It is not 17 versions. You are upgrading from 2.0 -> 2.1 -> 2.2. x.y.z where x is major, y is minor, z is bug fixes. Generally z changes are backwards compatible, as is y.

Answer (score 3):

I think I should read Cookbook:

first:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

then:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html

Comment: Very good idea. You can also run some of those upgrade commands: https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade - or at least look at the source code what else you could upgrade/fix/change/improve.